# Can't generate creation and update timestamps using @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimeStamp annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, timestamp

I'm trying to generate creation and update timestamps and as per [this jboss link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/generated/GeneratedValues.html) I have the following code inside my Hibernate model file:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "create_date")
private Date createDate;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "update_date")
private Date updateDate;
```

When I run my test, the Postgres server gives the following error "ERROR: null value in column "create_date" violates not-null constraint." after commiting.

However, everything works If I change the above code to the following:

```
private Date createDate;
private Date updateDate;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "create_date")
public Date getCreateDate() {
    return this.createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "update_date")
public Date getUpdateDate() {
    return this.updateDate;
}

public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}
```

I know that it should work using the first method as well, but I haven't been able to find why it won't work without the getters and setters.

Comment: Does that mean, you have no getters and setters at all, in your first version of the model?

Comment: Yea, didn't realize it needed a setter